# $S$ is a commutative integral domain and a finitely generated $R$-Module where $R$ is a subring of $S$. $R$ is a field iff $S$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, integral-domain

> Assume $S$ is a commutative integral domain, and $R \subseteq S$ is a subring. Assume $S$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module, i.e., there exist elements $s_1, \ldots, s_n \in S$ such that $S = s_1R + s_2R + \cdots + s_nR$.
>
> **(a)** Show that $R$ is a field if and only if $S$ is a field.
>
> **(b)** Is the statement true if the assumption that $S$ is an integral domain is dropped?

I haven't been able to do either direction.

Starting with the forward direction I assume $R$ is a field and consider a non-zero element $s ∈ S$ and write $s = s_1r_1 + · · · + s_nr_n$ then subtract the sum from both sides to get $s - s_1r_1 + · · · + s_nr_n = 0$. I want to try to use the integral domain fact by somehow writing the left side as a product like so: $s(1 - s^{-1}(s_1r_1 + · · · + s_nr_n)) = 0$ and since s is non-zero $1 - s^{-1}(s_1r_1 + · · · + s_nr_n) = 0$ and therefore $s^{-1}s = 1$ but there are obvious problems with that argument. Any help or hints would be appreciated. This is not a homework problem I am studying for a qual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finite algebra over a ring is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303040/finite-algebra-over-a-ring-is-a-field)

Comment: Yeah, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303040/finite-algebra-over-a-ring-is-a-field addresses the "if" part of part **(a)**. The "only if" part is because a matrix over a field that has zero kernel is invertible. As for **(b)**, all you need is find a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $k$ that is not a field. For example, $k\left[x\right]/x^2$ will do.